# Symfony relation loading fails (function getName() on null)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a symfony app with multipole relations and models, that worked well so far.
I have an App model with a sourceSystem relation defined like this

```
/**
 * @MaxDepth(2)
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="SourceSystem", inversedBy="apps")
 * @JoinColumn(name="sourceSystem_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $sourceSystem;
```

I now try to list the sourceSystems name in the view with `{{app.sourceSystem.name}}` which fails with `Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a null variable in appstore_admin\list_apps.html.twig at line 25.`.

Next up, in my controller I try

```
 /**
 * @Route("/contentstore_admin/", name="appstore_list_apps")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function listAppsAction()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:App');
    $apps = $repository->findAll();
    /** @var App $app */
    foreach ($apps as $app) {
        dump($app->getSourceSystem()->getName());
    }
    // check if the user already has a trial license
    return $this->render('appstore_admin/list_apps.html.twig', [
        "apps" => $apps
    ]);
}
```

Which fails with `Call to a member function getName() on null` **but** prints the system names into the debug bar.

I'm really confused by this behaviour and would like to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$app->getSourceSystem()` *can* returns a `null` value, you need to check it before using it.

```
$sourceSystem = $app->getSourceSystem();
if ($sourceSystem) {
    $name = $sourceSystem->getName();
}
```

or

```
{% if app.sourceSystem %}
    {{app.sourceSystem.name}}
{% endif %}
```

If you **don't want** `$sourceSystem` to be nullable, you can change the `nullable` attribute.

```
@JoinColumn(name="sourceSystem_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
```

Comment: Oh man, I'm stupid, apparently i do have three apps without association.